# How can I retain apparent detail when downsizing from 4608px to a 150px thumbnail?

Tags: rescaling, thumbnails

I shot profile pictures in RAW at a resolution of 4608(V)x3456(H). The client needs an image for their email signature with a width of approximately 150px wide. I have attempted this in PSCC2017 (with Bicubic Sharper), as well as LR saving in JPG, PNG, TIFF. The end result is always blurry at 72/96dpi. (Outlook wants 96dpi?)

Is there a technical way around this to make an image retain its sharpness at such a small scale?

What other things should I do next time I am shooting to avoid this?

Comment: Sharp the image after scaling down. (though your words about retaining sharpness "at such a small scale" make me think that you want to retain all the details of your 4608px image on 150px image. Is that true?)

Comment: If that's possible somehow, yes. I understand that it's technically not possible, but to make it appear to be is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: To me, it's a job that needs to be done by hand because the measure of the result is aesthetic not technical. Since it needs to be done by hand, it's something that needs to have a price attached to it. That price can be such that the client decides to do it themselves. It can be such that you can outsource the work and mark it up for a healthy profit. It can even be the case that you charge for a new photo session using a pose and lighting that is good for small format images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are an enormous number of scaling algorithms, but none of them will do enormously better than the common methods used in applications like PS.

If you want you can try something like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) which is a powerful graphics processing tool.  It has a large number of sampling methods and algorithms for sharpening and scaling one of which may get you a slightly better result for a particular image than another.  But the results won't be vastly different.

As I think you understand you're starting with 16 millions data points and ending with only 17 thousand points so you cannot retain anything like the same level of detail.  You may be able to emphasize certain feastures in the full image ( by exaggerating them with extreme sharpening ) to make them more obvious in the reduced size image, but that's probably all you can do.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that it's technically not possible

Basically 3456/150 = 23.04.

23.04 <sup>2</sup> = 530.84. Your target image has 530.84 times less information than the original.

---

I would first try to make a tighter crop, a more exact one.

Then resample it to your 150 px width.

And finally sharpen a bit the image.

The 72/96/whatever ppi does not matter. The file format either (unless you are trying to compress a JPG too much)

You could use Gimp or Photohsop.